# bootstrap-datetimepicker using maxDate sometimes does not display date

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

I am using the bootstrap-datetimepicker for date fields.  When setting maxDate to the current day, the normal behavior seems to be to pre-load the field with the current date.  When the user gets to that field, they are then able to change the date to a previous day if they would like.  Here is the code I use to initialize the datetimepicker:

```
$(".dateinput").datetimepicker({             //Initialize datepicker
        icons:
        {
            next: 'fa fa-angle-right',
            previous: 'fa fa-angle-left'
        },
    format: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
    maxDate: moment(),
});
```

Here is the HTML field

```
<input type="text" name="transaction_date" tabindex="15" class="dateinput form-control" required="" id="id_transaction_date">
```

About 10% of the time, when the page loads, the date field is empty.  The datepicker still works fine, dates in the future are not selectable, but there is simply no date in the field by default.

I created a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/he21nz9g/

If you run it multiple times, you will see that the date just does not appear sometimes - is this a known bug, or is there some way to get around it?

Comment: I just tried running your code 150 times, and the datepicker worked 150/150 times. Are you sure the problem isn't sometimes occurring because not all resources are loaded yet? Maybe try wrapping the JS in `$(window).load()` so that the code isn't executed until the entire window is loaded.

Comment: Thanks for trying it out.  Very strange - the jsfiddle about 1 out of 15 times shows a blank date for me.  I have tried different browsers and computers   All my js code is wrapped in a $(document).ready(function () {}

Comment: The date displays 100% if the time IF developer tools are on.  If developer tools are off, the problem seems to occur again.  This behavior maybe different in Firefox - a fresh browser start exhibits the problem, once developer tools are turned on, the problem disappears and I was not able to see the problem again once the developer tools were turned off again.  In Chrome, it's just dependent on developer tools being on or off...

Comment: Obviously, I'd like this to work with developer tools off...

Comment: Still not seeing this in Chrome, even with dev tools closed. Also, dev tools being open shouldn't make any difference. Have you tried running your code in an actual HTML file on your computer, or somewhere other than JSFiddle (CodePen, Repl.it, etc.)? I'd suspect the issue is just one of your resources isn't loading some of the time.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the CDN I was using was unreliable and occasionally did not load immediately.  I still see the problem even in the jsfiddle.  I have replaced it with another CDN that seems more reliable (CloudFlare).  Also, to make sure that the date always appears when maxDate is set, I simply set the field to today's date upon page load so whether the datepicker loads quickly enough or not, the date is always there.

When I initially chose this datepicker, I was not using JQuery ui.  I added JQuery ui later for other purposes and will likely swap in its datepicker at some point.